# Creating a long string from a result set

Tags: sql, t-sql, string

I have a result set in MS-SQL within a stored procedure, and lets say it has one VARCHAR column, but many rows. I want to create a comma separated string conataining all these values, Is there an easy way of doing this, or am I going to have to step through each result and build the string up manually?

Preferably I'd like to do this in the Stored Procedure itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is one way (using AdventureWorks2008 DB):

```
DECLARE @name varchar(255)
SET @name = NULL

select @Name = COALESCE(@Name + ',','') + LastName from Person.Person
Select @name
```

And here is another (for SQL 2005 onwards):

```
SELECT 
    LastName + ','
FROM 
    Person.Person
FOR XML PATH('')
```

In both cases you will need to remove the trailing comma ','  (can use STUFF() function)

Comment: The way I just discovered by myself :D