# Create varchar from SELECT result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008

```
DECLARE @result varchar(MAX)

SELECT 
  NAME
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  ID = @Id
```

I need to fill `@result` with result Names, separated by ','.
For example, if `SELECT` returns 'A','B' and 'C', the `@result` should be 'A, B, C'.
It is Microsoft SQL Server 2008.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a long string from a result set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/295575/creating-a-long-string-from-a-result-set)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
DECLARE @result varchar(MAX)
SET @result = '';

SELECT 
  @result = @result + NAME + ','
FROM
  Table
WHERE
  ID = @Id

SET @result = SUBSTRING(@result, 1, LEN(@result) - 1)

SELECT @result
```

Enjoy :D

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @CSV varchar(max)

SET @CSV = ''

SELECT @CSV = @CSV + Col1 + ',' FROM Table WHERE ...

SET @CSV = LEFT(@CSV, LEN(@CSV) -1)

PRINT @CSV
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
declare @result varchar(max)

select @result = COALESCE(@result + ', ', '') + name
from table
```

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE @Contribution AS VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @Contribution = 
(
SELECT RTRIM(Ltrim(C.strname)) + '; ' 
FROM tbl M
INNER JOIN tbl2 ON tbl2.ID =tbl.CID 
WHERE M.PID =@PID ORDER BY C.Orderby 
FOR XML PATH('')
)

Print @Contribution